# I am not able to store a .doc resume in the Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

Hibernate: `insert into data_files (file_content, file_name, doc_title, resume_text, title, title_id, file_type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not insert: [com.dckap.intranet.dto.FileUpload]; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into data_files (file_content, file_name, doc_title, resume_text, title, title_id, file_type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x96\xAA Re...' for column 'resume_text' at row 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x96\xAA Re...' for column 'resume_text' at row 1
```

I am getting the above error while storing a resume in data_files table.

1. The problem occurs only in the live db hosted in mocha host.
2. In local machine there is no problem  with the same resume

The datatypes are all same in both the db's tables.

Any idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be storing a binary document inside a varchar or CLOB column. Use a binary type to store binary data.

Comment: and one more thing is I use 'text' to do resume text search ...that requrement ll get affected

Comment: Maybe the local database uses a different char encoding.

Comment: How do you plan on searching into a Word document? .doc is a binary format. It's not text.

Comment: I do the conversions in my coding ...Actually my system comppletely works fine .. we did a host change 2 days back and the customer has uploaded one resume in .doc format and thats how i found this exception ... (BUT TO MENTION THIS DOES NOT OCCUR FOR ALL THE DOCUMENTS .. ONLY FEW DOCUMENTS )

Comment: What can I say? It probably happens to work sometimes because you're lucky, and the bytes of the doc file happen to represent valid characters in the encoding. You still shouldn't store binary data in a character column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6791/discussion-between-meenakshi-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to your the fact that you store the file in column that does not support this specific format. The problematic char according to the exception is a 'bullet' Check your InnoDB encoding settings. Storing the file itself on the file system and a path to it in your DB would be a better idea (IMO). You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3805520/579580) thread relevant.
Good Luck!

Comment: because of possible differences in InnoDB engine settings (encoding). however, i think that you missed the more important part: store the filepath in the DB and not the file.